when leaving the application and navigating to other sites it should get detected and when user is back to the application?
How can i do that on my oracle apex application
When user is leaving the application and navigating to other sites it should get detected and when user is back to the application with browser back button, should be asked for the authentication page.
When user is leaving the application and navigating to other sites it should get detected and when user is back to the application with browser back button, should be asked for the authentication page.
